# Bitlocker volume not mounting after upgrade to 20.04

Tags: encryption, 20.04

I received the notification that there is a new release and I upgraded to Focal Fossa. Everything seems to work fine till now, except that I lost access to the Bitlocker encrypted Windows partition.
I checked and the dislocker package is still installed; `/etc/fstab` hasn't changed, the dislocker-file is present.
When I try to mount it with `sudo mount -o loop /mnt/OS/dislocker-file /mnt/Windows` I get:

> mount: /mnt/Windows: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/loop13, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.

My fstab file entries are as follows:

> /dev/nvme0n1p3  /mnt/OS fuse.dislocker  recovery-password=myrecoverypassword 0 0
> /mnt/OS/dislocker-file /mnt/Windows  auto    nofail,x-gvfs-show,x-gvfs-name=C:   0   0

I checked the logs and am seeing a series of errors on a number of logical blocks:

> blk_update_request: I/O error, dev loop13, sector 469239680 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
>
> Buffer I/O error on dev loop13, logical block 58654960, async page read

How do I solve this issue?

Comment: Did you make sure that fast startup is off in windows?

Comment: Fast startup is off. I double-checked because in the past sometimes certain Windows updates would turn it back on, but this is not the case.

Comment: Did you try updating or re-installing the dislocker package?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to solve this problem by removing the dislocker package that was installed with apt:

```
sudo apt remove dislocker
```

Followed by installing the version from Github according to [this post](https://github.com/Aorimn/dislocker/issues/185#issuecomment-570794684). The steps to do this:

```
sudo apt install git gcc cmake make libfuse-dev libmbedtls-dev ruby-dev
git clone https://github.com/Aorimn/dislocker.git
cd dislocker
cmake .
make
sudo make install
```

Then I unmounted the dislocker-file with `sudo umount /mnt/OS` and remounted all partitions according to the `/etc/fstab` file with `sudo mount -a`.
Problem solved.